# Read (really) old dead trees ... er, plants ... let's call 'em texts online

Tags: discussion

Those of you involved in textual criticism and translation might want to check out the  [Leon Levy Dead Sea Scrolls Digital Library](http://www.deadseascrolls.org.il/) that [Google has sponsored](http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2012/12/in-beginningbringing-scrolls-of-genesis.html?m=1). They have posted like stuff before for several Dead Sea Scrolls including the great Isaiah scroll and some others, but this is a vastly expanded collection.